# take a photo from front camera and save it without button to take a picture or to save

Tags: android, camera

i want to take a photo from the front camera without any button to take the picture and save it automaticlly

my code:

```
final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/picFolder/";
                            File newdir = new File(dir);
                            newdir.mkdirs();
                            String file2 = dir+"test.jpg";
                            File newfile = new File(file2);
                            try {
                                newfile.createNewFile();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                            }

                            File image = new File(dir, "image.jpg");
                            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
                            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                            startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 0);
```